# How to make requests package send the UserAgent in a CONNECT command in Python?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a https site through a proxy server, and it seems, that requests package does not send the UserAgent by default, when submitting a CONNECT command.
Is there a way to force it?
I've seen that there are proxy_headers or tunnel_headers deep within the code, but how I access them?

```
import requests
import os

user = 'myuser'
pass_ = 'mypass'
proxy_ = 'myproxy.com:8080/'

os.environ["https_proxy"] = "https://"+user+":"+pass_+"@"+proxy_
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://"+user+":"+pass_+"@"+proxy_

hdr = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0'
}

webpage = 'https://example.com'
content = requests.get(webpage, headers=hdr).text
print(content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that currently it cannot be done with requests. :(